# How to increase packet size for reading webresponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamreader, httpwebresponse

I am reading response from a web url (in our own network), using `httpWebResponse`. While reading the response using `StreamReader ReadToEnd()`, It fetching data in packets and each packet having size of approx `500 bytes`.

How can I increase this packet size to approx `512 KB`?

Comment: so that I can receive all data in one shot.. in my case ReadToEnd() taking approx 4 second while downloading the 512 KB data.

Comment: Changing the packet size isn't going to help; it's just a slow server or connection.

Answer (score 1):

The packet size isn't (primarily) up to the *fetching* code - it's up to the server what size of packet it sends out, and those packets may be further split up by the rest of the network.

You simply can't have a TCP/IP packet of 512K... and you shouldn't care. This is just how TCP/IP works; it's not like it's making several HTTP requests for the data, it's just using the normal TCP/IP channel.

Have a look at fetching the same data from a browser - you'll see it split into packets in the same way.

EDIT: I see from your comments that it's taking 4 seconds to get the data. Yes, that's quite a long time - but that may well just be how long it takes to fetch/create and transport the data. You haven't really given much context here (what's a "webuser"?) but I think you're trying to optimize in the wrong place.

Comment: @Vjs: What do you mean by "in same network"? If it's on an internal corporate network, then it taking 4 seconds to transfer 512K is almost certainly because the web server is taking that long to actually find/create the content. The packet size is *not* your problem here.